# Page timing out with 404 error when script runs longer than 120 seconds

Tags: http-status-code-404, sleep

I have a script that needs to run for up to 15 minutes through a cron job.  But I can't get the script to stay running.  It errors out with a 404 message at exactly 120 seconds.  Very strange.  I have even called my hosting provider.  I am at a loss.

I have set max_execution_time = 5000

Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
set_time_limit(0);

$array = array('1','2', '3');

foreach ($array as $row) {

    echo $row . '<br>';
                 sleep(50);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also need to look at Apache's timeout setting, as you can change the max execution time value in php.ini and still get stopped by Apache's timeout value in the httpd.conf file.

You can find httpd.conf by running httpd -V in terminal (The command name depends on your system/apache version, it can be also apache -V) ~ If you don't have terminal access, you may need to contact your webhost. Example output:

```
bash-3.2# httpd -V
Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Unix)
Server built:   Aug 24 2012 17:16:58
Server's Module Magic Number: 20051115:30
Server loaded:  APR 1.4.5, APR-Util 1.3.12
Compiled using: APR 1.4.5, APR-Util 1.3.12
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     Prefork
  threaded:     no
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APACHE_MPM_DIR="server/mpm/prefork"
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_FLOCK_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=128
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/usr"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/bin/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/private/var/run/httpd.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_LOCKFILE="/private/var/run/accept.lock"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="/private/etc/apache2/mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf"     <-- HERE IT IS
```

httpd.conf could look like this: https://www.devside.net/guides/config/linux/httpd-conf

Notice the line:

```
Timeout 300
```

Comment: ok. dumb question... where can I find that file?  Will I need to contact my web host?

Comment: I haven't taken the time to search for that but... can I find it without using a terminal?  And if I do locate that file will it show a similar line as to max_execution_time = 120?

Comment: Doing a brief search... it appears that my host, dreamhost, does not allow httpd.conf file editing.  They indicated that I could edit my .htaccess file.  Any thoughts on how to do that?  And to check if it is working properly after I do make the change (other than successful running of long script)?

Comment: .htaccess does not handle timeouts. And successful running of your script would be the best test I can think of.

Comment: I don't know what the post I was looking at said... I just saw httpd.conf for dreamhost.  The .htacess probably isn't relevant

Comment: Here's a handy resource if you'd like to know more about how you can use .htaccess: http://www.htaccess-guide.com/

Comment: https://discussion.dreamhost.com/thread-146831-post-187578.html#pid187578

"Thanks for contacting DreamHost. The FastCGI timeout is set to 120
seconds or two minutes. I actually have a bug open with our tech ops team
to provide some sort of option to allow customers to increase the timeout
limit, at least on a VPS, but it is still being talked about so nothings
close to being pushed out yet..."

Comment: I ran this script on a bare site and the error is actually a 500.  And thanks to SLWS it appears it has to do with FastCGI timeout.